# Использование параметра uri от API Геосаджест в API Геокодер

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Разбираюсь с сервисом API Геосаджест.  В документации сказано, что значение параметра uri из ответа от API можно использовать в API Геокодер вместо адреса или координат.  Никак не могу разобраться, как его передавать.

Например, получил от Геосаджеста: `"uri":"ymapsbm1://geo?data=Cgg1MzAwMDAwMRIM0KDQvtGB0YHQuNGP"`

Пробовал в передать его в Геокодер в разном виде:

`"geocode":"ymapsbm1://geo?data=Cgg1MzAwMDAwMRIM0KDQvtGB0YHQuNGP"`

`"geocode":"geo?data=Cgg1MzAwMDAwMRIM0KDQvtGB0YHQuNGP"`

`"geocode":"data=Cgg1MzAwMDAwMRIM0KDQvtGB0YHQuNGP"`

`"geocode":"Cgg1MzAwMDAwMRIM0KDQvtGB0YHQuNGP"`

`"uri":"ymapsbm1://geo?data=Cgg1MzAwMDAwMRIM0KDQvtGB0YHQuNGP"`

Результата или не получаю или он не соответствует точке из Геосаджеста.

Comment: Видно, что в последовательности закодировано число и текст подсказки, если попробовать развернуть как base64. Но подстановка в Геокодер действительно не работает. Может нужен какой-то особый параметр и там? Раз в документации нет, это надо поддержку трясти.

Answer (score 0):

Получил правильную структуру запроса от поддержки Яндекса:

```
https://geocode-maps.yandex.ru/1.x/?apikey=<ваш API-ключ>&lang=ru_RU&sco=latlong&uri=ymapsbm1://geo?data=Cgg1MzAwMDAwMRIM0KDQvtGB0YHQuNGP
```